# How can I play a .psv file on windows machine?

Tags: windows-10, media-player

I have a Windows 10 machine on which I want to play a .psv file.

I've tried vlc, mpc-hc and windows media player in vain.

How can I play a .psv file on my windows machine?

Comment: What kind of file is that even supposed to be? All I get is PlayStation 2 save file, but that’s obviously not a video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you need, if I think you're looking for what I just did. 
https://github.com/KevinWang15/PsVDecrypt

Comment: You need to explain a bit more what your code does...

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.